# Stanford NLP: dependency tree results different between online and offline versions

Tags: stanford-nlp

I wanted to parse the following example using the Stanford Core NLP suite using the dependency parser:

```
Call a yellow cab for James on Piccadilly Street in 5 minutes
```

I have parsed this sentence using the:

- [suite downloaded package](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-latest.zip) from https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/(so i ran it offline, locally, on my computer):

> ```
> Dependency Parse (enhanced plus plus dependencies):
> root(ROOT-0, Call-1)
> det(cab-4, a-2)
> amod(cab-4, yellow-3)
> obj(Call-1, cab-4)
> case(James-6, for-5)
> nmod:for(cab-4, James-6)
> case(Street-9, on-7)
> compound(Street-9, Piccadilly-8)
> nmod:on(cab-4, Street-9)
> case(minutes-12, in-10)
> nummod(minutes-12, 5-11)
> nmod:in(cab-4, minutes-12)
> ```

- [online website](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp)(so I ran it on the provided website, online):

> ```
> Universal dependencies, enhanced
> root(ROOT-0, Call-1)
> det(cab-4, a-2)
> amod(cab-4, yellow-3)
> obj(Call-1, cab-4)
> case(James-6, for-5)
> obl:for(Call-1, James-6)
> case(Street-9, on-7)
> compound(Street-9, Piccadilly-8)
> obl:on(Call-1, Street-9)
> case(minutes-12, in-10)
> nummod(minutes-12, 5-11)
> nmod:in(Street-9, minutes-12)
> ```

The online generated result is correct while the other one is not.

Can anybody help me understand why are the results different considering also that the online version is as old as 2016 and the downloaded version is since 2020? I would like to have the same results using the downloaded version as with the online version.

Can anybody help me understand the difference?

**P.S.**

I have also tried using the `stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31` version of core nlp - received the same result.

I have also copied the [English model](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-4.1.0-models-english.jar) inside the `stanford-corenlp-4.1.0` folder with no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the online version is first constituency parsing the sentence and then converting to a dependency parse. The other example might be from the neural dependency parser.

So if you try just using the `parse` annotator (and don't use the `depparse` annotator), you should get the results you want.

Comment: I was able to match the online with recent CoreNLP using the conversion of the constituency parse.

Comment: Any idea, is it possible to obtain this result using Lynten(https://github.com/Lynten/stanford-corenlp)?
I could edit `StanfordCoreNlp.parse` or add another method to the class in https://github.com/Lynten/stanford-corenlp/blob/master/stanfordcorenlp/corenlp.py but I'm not sure which are the arguments to use for the constituency parsing. Are the there some parameters documented somewhere for this? Regards!